# Why KeyboardInterrupt is not working in multithreading

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I am actually tring to write Python code in which read / write from a socket is handlded in different thread - objective is that to write 5 times in a socket and then read the same then again write and read and so on - till now I have not yet achieved the objective but facing a problem during its development:

The **KeyboardInterrupt** in my code is not working - I am not sure why?

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import sys

exit = False

def rxThread(rxSocket):
    global exit    
    while not exit:
        try:
            data,addr = rxSocket.recvfrom(1024) 
            print (data)
        except socket.error:
            pass
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            exit = True
            print ("Received Ctrl+C... initiating exit")

def txThread(portNum):
    global exit

def main():    
    global exit
    UDP_IP="100.108.9.105"
    UDP_PORT=1000      
    sleep(.1)

    #Generate a transmit socket object
    txSocket = sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    #Do not block when looking for received data (see above note)
    txSocket.setblocking(0) 
    udpRxThreadHandle = Thread(target=rxThread,args=(txSocket,))    
    udpRxThreadHandle.start()
    try:
        string="30 29 02 01 00 04 06 00"  
        arr = string.split(" ")
        barr = bytearray()
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            barr.append(int(arr[i], 16))
        #Transmit data to the local server on the agreed-upon port
        for i in range(1,2,1):
            sock.sendto(barr,(UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
    except socket.error:    
        #If no data is received you end up here, but you can ignore
        #the error and continue
        pass   
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit = True
        udpRxThreadHandle.join()
        print ("Received Ctrl+C... initiating exit")
    sleep(.1)
    udpRxThreadHandle.join()
    return

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

I am not sure how to achieve the objective?

Answer (score 0):

In python, only the main thread receives a signal. If you use it to close the datagram socket, `recvfrom` will raise an `OSError` and you can exit the thread. You likely can remove the `exit` variable completely. As a minimum, change its name so that it doesn't shadow the builtin `exit()` function.

```
import socket
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep
import sys

# todo: if this is just to handle the keyboardinterrupt case, remove
exit = False

def rxThread(rxSocket):
    global exit    
    while not exit:
        try:
            data,addr = rxSocket.recvfrom(1024) 
            print (data)
        except socket.error:
            pass
        except OSError:
            exit = True
            print ("Socket closed... initiating exit")

def txThread(portNum):
    global exit

def main():    
    global exit
    UDP_IP="100.108.9.105"
    UDP_PORT=1000      
    sleep(.1)

    #Generate a transmit socket object
    txSocket = sock=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_DGRAM)

    #Do not block when looking for received data (see above note)
    txSocket.setblocking(0) 
    udpRxThreadHandle = Thread(target=rxThread,args=(txSocket,))    
    udpRxThreadHandle.start()
    try:
        string="30 29 02 01 00 04 06 00"  
        arr = string.split(" ")
        barr = bytearray()
        for i in range(len(arr)):
            barr.append(int(arr[i], 16))
        #Transmit data to the local server on the agreed-upon port
        for i in range(1,2,1):
            sock.sendto(barr,(UDP_IP,UDP_PORT))
    except socket.error:    
        #If no data is received you end up here, but you can ignore
        #the error and continue
        pass   
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        exit = True
        sock.close()
        print ("Received Ctrl+C... initiating exit")
    udpRxThreadHandle.join()
    return

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks I made the changes as mentioned but still it is not gracefully exiting - I actually need to close the console - when I put print statement then it seems is in always throwing  except socket.error in rxThread method

Comment: You get `socket.error` a lot since you are reading a non-blocking socket (likely you want blocking). I can't run your code but when I created a datagram socket and closed it, recvfrom raised OSError, at least on my ubuntu system. You could print `socket.error` and see which subtypes you get.

Comment: No my side the server is kept running my code will send data and read the response - this is the error I get on socket.error in rxThread - [WinError 10035] A non-blocking socket operation could not be completed immediately